# Persistent state using vuex-persistedstate: store state in first tab doesnot update when i mutate state in another tab

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Hi I am using vuex persistedstate to persist my state.

```
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

const store = new Vuex.Store({
// ...
    plugins: [createPersistedState()]
})
```

What I want to do is update a store state in another tab and the updated store state should be reflected in other open tabs of my app.

How can I achieve so.

Answer (score 1):

Use for it **vuex-shared-mutations**:

[GitHub link](https://github.com/xanf/vuex-shared-mutations)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing a `window.onfocus` event so that when that you go to the new tab, the `getState` method gets called.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the `storage` event. See *Responding to storage changes with the StorageEvent* in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API .

```
window.addEventListener("storage", e => {
    // ...
});
```

Example: https://github.com/jacobgoh101/vuex-sync-tabs-example

in store.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import createPersistedState from "vuex-persistedstate";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  plugins: [createPersistedState()],
  state: {
    count: 2
  },
  mutations: {
    increment(state) {
      state.count++;
    },
    setAll(state, payload) {
      state.count = payload.count;
    }
  },
  actions: {}
});
```

in App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    store count: {{$store.state.count}}
    <br>
    <button @click="$store.commit('increment')">add</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "app",
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener("storage", e => {
      if (e.key !== "vuex") return;

      // exit if no change
      if (e.newValue === JSON.stringify(this.$store.state)) return;

      const persistedData = JSON.parse(e.newValue);

      this.$store.commit("setAll", persistedData);
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: How about storage using cookies?